# Angular Reactive form's formArrays not binding as intended on sort

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, angular-reactive-forms

Reactive form control couldn't be sort. Places received from Google place autocomplete saved in an array, then I changed its order in the array. When I console log I see the array has changed the order but it doesn’t bind to the UI.
Added the code in the stackblitz.

Steps to produce the error:

1. Add three address (autocomplete) and  pincode
2. and click on sort address button. Now you see the pincode change every time you click on sort address button but not the address

Here is the code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-fq6zd5?file=app/app.component.ts):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
        addresses: this._fb.array([
            this.initAddress(),
        ])
    });
}

sortAddress() {
    const B = [2, 1, 0];
    this.myForm.get('addresses').setValue(B.map((entry) => 
        this.myForm.get('addresses').value[entry]));
}

initAddress() {
    return this._fb.group({
        street: ['', Validators.required],
        postcode: ['']
    });
}

addAddress() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['addresses'];
    control.push(this.initAddress());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add value modification to your `writeValue()` function:

```
public writeValue(value: any) {
  if (!value || value === null) {
    this.resetLocation();
    // this.updatePhotoComponent(value);
  }
  // this line actually writes changed value into its input box
  else {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.location.nativeElement, 'value', value.address);
  }
}
```

Updated STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-eqve8a?file=app/google-place.component.ts

Comment: Thanks. Why should we set property through writevalue?

Comment: `<app-google-place ...>` is a custom form element that you wrote, its model is updated through `formControlName` attribute, which is watched by `writeValue` function and it is custom element's responsibility to update its view (it may be done in many ways: using `ngModel`, reactive forms approach, native element update, ...etcl). You used native element approach to reset location value, but you covered only case of empty value, I added element update in case of non-empty value.